# Extend node application with new actions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've created application which is handle some basic actions like save(e.g. saving a file in file system) edit etc ,now I want that some users will have the ability to extend this functionality with new actions,for example user
will clone the application and add additional file with new actions (and some callback) and then register on some event

I should this new actions under the hood,my question is how can I take this new actions from new file and run then in my process,simple example will be very helpful

**UPDATE**
lets assume that this is my file that handle the action and user want to add additional action like delete

```
var fs = require('fs');
module.exports = {
    fileAction: function (req, res, filePath) {
        var urlAction = urlPath.substr(urlPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        if (urlAction === 'save') {
            this.save(req,res,filePath);
        } else
            this.delete(req,res,filePath);
    },

    save: function (req,res,filePath) {
        var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath, {flags: 'w'});
        req.pipe(writeStream);
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    },

    delete: function (req,res,filePath) {

    },

}
```

and the delete code should be something like this

```
 filePath = 'C://test.txt';
    fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
```

Now as `lordvlad` suggest user should have a new file with his specific implementation which should be used by `lordvlad` suggestion design flow,my question is how to add this delete functionality(which is very simple) and **make it work**,like some **POC** for this.

Comment: its not clear from your question what you really want, can you post some code example or high level psuedo code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could imagine some plugin system like so:

main.js

```
// some setup
var EE = require('events').EventEmitter;
var glob = require('glob');
var eventBus = new EE();

// find plugins
glob("plugins/*.js", function(err, files) {
  if (err) {
    // some error handling here
  }

  files.forEach(function(file) {
    var plugin = require(file);
    plugin(eventBus);
  });
});
```

plugins/my-plugin.js

```
module.exports = function(eventBus) {
  // do something interesting

  // listen for events on the event bus
  eventBus.on("foo", function(e){ 
    // do something 
  });


  eventEmitter.emit("pluginReady", "my-plugin");
};
```

Of course you could substitute the event emitter with some global object, or make the plugin handle callbacks by passing a callback instead of an event bus. I think the key aspect is to load plugins (done within the `glob ... require` block) and and to make them fit into your system (which you will need to figure out yourself or provide some code samples of what you already have so somebody can give you another hint).

**UPDATE** after OPs update

main.js

```
var glob = require('glob');
var xtend = require('xtend');



module.exports = {
  save: function(..){..},
  load: function(..){..},
}

// typeof module.exports.delete === 'undefined',
// so you cannot call module.exports delete or similar

glob("plugins/*.js", function(err, files) {
  files.forEach(function(file){
    var plugin = require(file);

    // call plugin initializer if available
    if (typeof plugin.init === "function")
      plugin.init();

    xtend(module.exports, plugin);
  });


  // here all plugins are loaded and can be used
  // i.e. you can do the following
  module.exports.delete(...);
});
```

plugins/my-plugin.js

```
module.exports = {
  delete: function(..){..},
  init: function() {
    // do something when the plugin loads
  }
}
```

Mind though, that any plugin could overwrite another plugin's methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot its very interesting,voted up! why do you use the event bus?,I need that user send some callback...Can you provide some sample for implementation with this paradigm since I want to verify that this design is working...lets say I've already one function which is handling save (please see my updated post)and user extend my functionality with delete file,Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks!one question when I provide my code I've just save and not delete or load since this is something that should come from the user I just need to call this functionality...like the delete functionality which I provide in the updated post

Comment: in addition I use the xtend(module.exports, plugin); but inside the module I've some method to run such as delete,how should I call it dynamically ?Thanks in advance expert!

Comment: Thanks a lot expert!,another question why should I use module.exports.delete(...); if I've a init,In the init user can say this.delete and this action will be invoked....can you please explain? maybe this is better design 2. there is option to pass parameters to the actions from the main?if yes how, lets say every time you pass for every action (req,res,path)....

Comment: well, I thought you meant 'plugins' with 'extend'. Otherwise its just simple module handling. You wouldn't even need the `init` methods, because the modules are executed when they are required.

Comment: I need the plug-able  mechanism ,my question is how the xtend(module.exports, plugin); is helping to this scenario ? 2. why I dont need the init ? AFAIK when you call to a module you need to call to the specific function inside to do whatever you want ....with the init I think you could say to the plugin creator to be responsible on process ,correct me if im wrong...3.what is the recommended way to pass params which is equal to all the plugin like (req,res,path),Thanks in advance I learning a lot from you :)

Comment: maybe you should find a tutorial on node basics? here's a start http://nodeguide.com/beginner.html#the-module-system

Comment: Ok I already know nodeJS the issue here that I need to create extendible plugin mechanism ,you give me good Idea's...i'lll take it from there so I marked this answer as solved,but can you please answer my 3 question in the previos comment ?Thanks and have a good weekend!